# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-mapping

I have to ask it, I almost tried everything.

Entity Class

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserInfo")
public class User {

    @Id@Column(name="user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Integer userId;
}
```

---

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=BankingApplication</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">2OmniWay</property>

        <!-- org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured! -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
         <property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</property>
        <!-- Mapping with model class containing annotations -->
        <mapping class="pojo.User"/>
    </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

SeesionFactory

```
// Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml");
System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation Configuration loaded");
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().                                    applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
 System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation serviceRegistry created");             
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

return sessionFactory;
```

Getting Object saved in DB

---

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Account account = null;
        try{
        account = (Account) session.get(Account.class, id);
```

I am getting exception mentioned in subject. I just tripled checked everything but it is just not working.[image]

Any suggestion would be helpful.

___________Stack Trace_________

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: pojo.User
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:792)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2652)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2500(SessionImpl.java:164)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2590)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2577)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1044)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:955)
at business.ManageAccount.getAccountDetails(ManageAccount.java:18)
at Utils.TestConnecttion.main(TestConnecttion.java:16)
```

Comment: Where is stacktrace?

Comment: how is this finally solved?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specifically add the entity classes in the configuration.
By default it loads the classes but do not initialize the entity classes.
For that configuration.addAnnotatedClass() or addResource will solve this out.

Comment: by using addAnnotatedClass, it is working. But it is not good design if I have to specify each entity while creating SessionFactory. I want this to be part of configuration. idea ??

Comment: For that you need you create .hbm for every entity and configure that hbm file with hibernate.cfg.xml. I think this is the only way to make it a part of configuration.

Answer (score 1):

replace your code

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
.applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
```

from SessionFactory to

```
ServiceRegistry  serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()). buildServiceRegistry();
```

and try to make your sessionfactory and serviceRegistry  static in class

May it works for you.

Comment: what version of hibernate you are using

Answer (score 1):

```
//I am using Hib5,I have created SF like this and it is working
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your User not implemented Serializable, try with this:

```
 public class User implements Serializable{
   }
```

Comment: It is compile time exception. addAnnotatedClass is method of configuration object.

Comment: I have added configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Account.class); line after  configuration.configure("hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml");
and it works. But I want to know why it is not picking mappings from cfg.xml files ?

Comment: you added only User.java to cfg.xml file ,what about other Entities?

Comment: I have added all entities in cfg.xml. Hibernate is not picking any of them, be it User or Account. I have shown cfg.xml as short as possible. I want Hibernate to pick mapping from cfg.xml not from solution provided above. any view ?

Comment: @vineeshchauhan see the answer

Comment: public class User implements Serializable{ } - Good catch but no impact.

Comment: @youshchauhan if are you reach a answer canyou share with us thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate version 6.0 moves from Java Persistence as defined by the Java EE specs to Jakarta Persistence. Instead of using the entity of java persistence use Jakarta.

Answer (score -2):

You did not add Dialect to your Hibernate config file.Add this line in your config file.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
```

Comment: It is automatically loaded. I can see it in logs. something is wrong somewhere else.

Comment: I have also added but no success.

Answer (score -2):

Your syntax works in Hibernate 4.x, but causes an error with Hibernate 5.x.

The configuration file causes this problem.
In the configuration XML file, you added a mapping file, such as:

```
mapping resource="hibernate.map.xml"
```

Remove this and add this programatically instead:

```
configure.addResource(hibernate.map.xml);
```

It will surely work.